# What does the html attributes data-number-to-fixed and data-number-stepfactor mean?

Tags: html

When trying to use the HTML5 input type number for currency i am seeing the attributes **data-number-to-fixed** and **data-number-stepfactor** used along with the **step** attribute. Are these data attributes needed when defining an input that deals with currency? What are they particularly used for?

Here is a JSFiddle example I was looking at for dealing with currency that used those attributes.

[HTML  number - Currency Example](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/UC6tG/)

and here is a snippet of the code I am referring to from that example

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="c2">Currency w bootstrap</label>
<div class="input-group"> 
    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
    <input type="number" value="1000" min="0" 
      step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" 
      data-number-stepfactor="100" class="form-control currency" id="c2" />
</div>
```

Comment: In this case, those fields are specific to the webshim library: https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/